# codeigniter form_radio how to get values in controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have multiple radio buttons and a dropdown list. I want to populate the list based on the selected value. The problem is I can't get the selected value in controller. 
View:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'controller/method');
 $type1 = array(
'name' => 'category',
'id'=> '1',
'value' => 't1',
'checked' => TRUE,
);
echo form_radio($type1);
echo form_label('Type 1');
$type2 = array(
'name' => 'category',
'id'=> '2',
'value' => 't2',
);
echo form_radio($type2);
echo form_label('Type 2');
$type3 = array(
'name' => 'category',
'id'=> '3',
'value' => 't3',
);
echo form_radio($type3);
echo form_label('Type 3');
echo form_close();
 ?>
```

Controller:

```
$category= $this->input->post('category');
```

When I try:

```
if(isset($category)){
   echo $category;
}
else{
   echo "variable is not there";
}
```

I always get "variable is not there".

Comment: try <?php echo form_open('controller/method'); CodeIgniter automatically adds the base_url to the action of the form when you use the form helper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: @beginner solved ??

Comment: no I can't get the value in controller